# pandas dataframe using different mean for standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, standard-deviation

Is there a way to perform standard deviation on an array where you specify the the xi and xn variable?  it appears that the standard deviation function uses the mean of the respected series.  For example if I have a dataframe DF with 2 columns d and c, I would like the standard deviation function to perform is as stddev=sqrt(1/df.index*cumsum((DF.d-DF.c)^2)`.

Edit: Here is the dataframe

```
    d         c
```

0  1.8740  1.874000
1  1.8762  1.876114
2  1.8735  1.874886
3  1.8740  1.874633
4  1.8754  1.874746
5  1.8716  1.874110
6  1.8696  1.873351
7  1.8732  1.873324
8  1.8656  1.871752
9  1.8613  1.870247

In the pandas std class, it will calculate standard dev by using the mean of column D.  I would like to and perform the calucation using an alternate calculated mean in column c.  Basically column C is weighted average.   I wanted to use the expanding_std class but no way, that I can see to define the mean variable.

Comment: I cannot quite follow you here. Do you want to calculate SD of column A but use the mean of column B instead?

Comment: You used `cumsum` in your example.  Is that correct, or did you mean `sum`?